# Generate alphanumeric random numbers in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want random numbers 100000+, I found numpy is suitable for my project based on performance it is good. But I want 4 places random number based on below pattern,

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
```

In the above case 26 small letters,26 capital letters and 10 digits equal to 62 total letters and let us take permutation and combinations,

I want 4 digits from those letters so,

```
62 ^ 4 / 4! = 615680 (Combinations)
```

If I take  26 small letters + 10 digits and the output is,

```
(26+10) ^ 4 / 4! = 69984 (Combinations)
```

From those two cases first one is best, It provides better random numbers, I did some logic here,

```
from numpy.random.mtrand import RandomState
import binascii
lo = 1000000000000000
hi = 999999999999999999
In [65]: %timeit [ binascii.b2a_hex(rand.randint(lo, hi, 2).tostring())[:4] for _ in xrange(100000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 272 ms per loop
```

But the random number count is below 100000, Because it only takes small lettes + digits

```
In [66]: len(set([binascii.b2a_hex(rand.randint(lo, hi, 2).tostring())[:4] for _ in xrange(100000)]))
Out[66]: 51210
```

Any one suggest me how to implement this in numpy ?

Comment: `numpy.random.choice()` 4-vectors from the alphabet, and then `''.join()` each?

Comment: Or if you told us the actual problem you are trying to solve, we might be able to better help you.

Comment: @NPE thanks for reply, I am trying to generate the random numbers 100000 for every time. So I need to save every unique random number into nosql db. And what is the problem is I want 4 places random number . 62 letters gives more unique random numbers compare to 36 letters. So from above logic it takes 32 letters not 64 letters.

Comment: Typically people use base 64 for this, which is your alphabet and the character '+' and '/'. This makes everything easier as you are now just generating a random number and then doing a base 64 conversion against it.

Comment: @Claris perhaps you can post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out by NPE, you can use numpy.random.choice.
Does this code achieve what you want?

```
import numpy as np

LENGTH = 4
NO_CODES = 100000

alphabet = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
np_alphabet = np.array(alphabet, dtype="|S1")
np_codes = np.random.choice(np_alphabet, [NO_CODES, LENGTH])
codes = ["".join(np_codes[i]) for i in range(len(np_codes))]

print(codes)
```

It takes a couple of seconds to execute with `NO_CODES = 1000000` on my 2-years-old but not bad computer.

Comment: Running this on python 3.5 gives me the error message `sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.bytes_ found`

Comment: Try changing dtype to ``dtype="|U1"``

Answer (score 8):

It can be done much faster by using numpy view.

```
A, Z = np.array(["A","Z"]).view("int32") 

NO_CODES = 100
LEN = 20

np.random.randint(low=A,high=Z,size=NO_CODES*LEN,dtype="int32").view(f"U{LEN}")
```

Comment: This is great - thank you! It's about 10X faster than the `np.random.choice(np_alphabet, [NO_CODES, LENGTH])` approach

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the other two answers worked for me, but I was able to use them to create the following solution:

```
import numpy as np

length  = 4
n_codes = 100000
alpha_num = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')

np_codes = np.random.choice(alpha_num, size=[n_codes, length])
codes = [''.join(code) for code in np_codes]
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer can be made a bit faster with the following code:

```python
import numpy as np

length  = 4
n_codes = 100000
alpha_num = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')

np_codes = np.random.choice(alpha_num, size=[n_codes, length])
codes = [code.tostring() for code in np_codes]
```

Original runtime on my machine: `10 loops, best of 3: 204 ms per loop`.

New runtime: `10 loops, best of 3: 27.6 ms per loop`.